# VBA Excel UserForm ComboBox Populate/Add

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, userform

I have a dynamic Name range that I want to populate a UserForm `ComboBox` with.

```
Range1=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,1,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1,1)
```

How do I populate the `combobox` with this range and use the `combobox` to add and sort the range upon entry?

Comment: First off, welcome to Stackoverflow. So Stackoverflow isn't exactly a good place for "I don't know how to code this, code this for me" which is how you're coming off, you probably mean to say, and should say something more like "I don't know how to code this, I've tried X, but doesn't work, what's wrong with X and how can I fix X.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I am not going to give you code on a platter but I can surely get you on the right track :)

**First things First**

`COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1` is the wrong way to find the last row number. What if the Col A has blanks?

Use `=MAX((A:A<>"")*(ROW(A:A)))` instead. This is an array formula. Which means that you have to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> if you are using it directly in a worksheet. If you are using it in a named range then you do not have to worry about it.

[image]

**Secondly**

To loop through a range and add to a combobox, you can use this code

```
Dim aCell As Range

For Each aCell In MYRANGE
    Combobox1.AddItem aCell.Value
Next aCell
```

**Thirdly**

To add to a range, you can simply use

```
Range("A1").Value = Combobox1.value
```

**Lastly**

To sort a range

```
'~~> Where ws is the relevant worksheet
ws.Columns("A:AE").Sort Key1:=ws.Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
```

You can use the `Combobox1` click event to perform the addition and sorting of the range

Hope this gets you in the right track :)